# The size of the intel block is invalid (python)

Tags: python, file, hex, xlsm

I created code to convert an xlsm file to a hex file.
So far, it's working.

After creating the file that contains the data (in 32bit), I need to change the address of the fist data, and update the following address. I did it for an address of 4 (0000) but I need to do it for a address of 8 (0000 0000).
When I try to change the address of the data in the file, it seem that my hexadecimal file isn't valid (Like in the screen shot).

Example Screenshot of file

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can change this ?

Code sample;

```py
def defineNewAdresse(name_file):
    with open(name_file, "rb") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        adr_list = list(map(lambda x: x[3:6], content))

    if not adr_list:
        adr_list.append("")

    adr_first = checkHexa()
    adr_list[0] = adr_first
    bin_list = []
    formatted_hexa = []

    for i in range(1, len(adr_list)):
        previous_value = int(adr_list[i - 1], 16)
        current_value = previous_value + 16
        adr_list[i] = hex(current_value)[2:].zfill(8)

    for hex_value in adr_list:
        adr_decimal = int(hex_value, 16)
        adr_binary = bin(adr_decimal)[2:]
        bin_list.append(adr_binary)

    for binary_value in bin_list:
        binary_string = format(int(binary_value, 2), "032b")
        hex_num = hex(int(binary_string, 2))[2:].zfill(4)
        formatted_hexa.append(hex_num.zfill(8))

    for i in range(len(content)):
        if i < len(formatted_hexa):
            line = content[i].decode("utf-8")
            modified_line = line[:3] + formatted_hexa[i] + line[7:]
            content[i] = modified_line.encode("utf-8")

    with open(name_file, "wb") as f:
        f.write(b"".join(content))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Please share a [mre].

Comment: Coudn't put the screen shot but here is a exemple :

:200870abcd00508ECC7CF70100009057AF7CF7010000B031007DF7010000B08E4566F701000081
r
The last 4 characters are behind the checksum.

Comment: Don't post screenshots, paste the data and results as text into the question. Use a code block to format it.